# CSS Make image take up a certain percentage of viewport

Tags: css, viewport-units

I am working on a website that has a slideshow right under the header.  I want to limit the height of the slideshow responsively so that if it leaves 20-30% of the viewport on one screen resolution, it will do the same on the other.  Currently my CSS looks like this.

```
#slideshow-container {
    height: 70vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slideshow-container img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The images scale responsively and I'm using the viewport units to accomplish what I want.  However, viewport units aren't very cross-browser compatible so I'm looking for a way to accomplish the same idea across all browsers.  I'd prefer to only use CSS and not JavaScript or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know your markup, it's more difficult to help.
I'd do it with following lines of CSS:

```
/*reset stuff so that body fits the entire viewport*/
html,
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#slideshow-container {
     height:70%;
     ...
}
```

This should do the job.

But in my opinion there's propably no reason for not using viewport units since it's supported in most current browsers: http://caniuse.com/viewport-units
The only problem shall be the mobile devices (and IE, of course).